# Prove the function is continious.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If the function $f(x)$ is continious at $x=0$, using definitions show that $f(rx)$ is continious at $x=0$. Here $r$ is a real number.

Answer (score 1):

We know that for *any* $\;\epsilon >0\;$ there exists $\;\delta>0\;$ such that

$$|x|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(0)|<\epsilon$$

Well, now just choose $\;\delta':=\delta |r|\;$ , and then

$$|xr|<\delta'\iff |x||r|<\delta|r|\implies |x|<\delta\implies |f(rx)-f(0)|<\epsilon$$

and from here that

$$\lim_{x\to0}f(rx)=f(0)$$